# Passing multidimensional arrays (without initially defining its dimensions) into a function in C++

Tags: c++

I have been looking for code on how to create a matrix determinant calculator, and I found code from ( [Matrix determinant algorithm C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220504/matrix-determinant-algorithm-c) ).

I adopted the code to try it, but i realized that i did not know how to pass in a multidimensional array into the function, without defining its dimensions first (i got errors).

So, can you please show me how to pass a multidimensional array into a function without defining its dimensions first (i.e how `int a[MAX][MAX]` is an argument, what is 'MAX').

I hope my question is clear, thank you for your help.

This is the (edited) code:
-sample input would be **a square matrix and its size**.

```
int determinant(int oMat[][], int n){

    int sMat[n][n]; //Temporary matrix
    int det = 0; //Initializing 'det'.

    if(n==1){
        det = oMat[0][0]; //Calculating.
        return det;
    }else if(n==2){
        det = oMat[0][0]*oMat[1][1] - oMat[1][0]*oMat[0][1]; //Formula for 2x2.
        return det;
    }else{

        for(int p=0; p<n; p++){ //Selecting 'oMat' row one.
            int k=0; //'sMat' rows.
            int m=0; //'sMat' columns.

            //Creating the temporary matrix 'sMat'.
            for(int i=1; i<n; i++){ //for 'oMat' rows.
                for(int j=0; j<n; j++){

                    if(j==p){
                        continue;
                    }

                    sMat[k][m] = oMat[i][j]; m++;


                    if(m==n-1){
                        k++; //Go to the next row.
                        m = 0; //Start at column one (index 0).
                    }
                }
            }

            det = det + oMat[0][p] * pow(-1,p) * determinant(sMat, n-1);

        }
        return det;
    }
}
```

Comment: You must mean how to pass multi dim arrays instead of parsing ?

Comment: How to pass I mean, I have just edited it. Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include sample input, the code you have actually tried, the actual and expected output from your code, and as many other details as possible.

Comment: Try writing the template function as template<class T, int R, int C> T dterm(T (&my_matrix)[R][C]){...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing a 2-D array to function `determ()` as

```
int a[MAX][MAX];
determ(a, int n);
```

the function declaration should be:

```
determ(int a[][MAX], int n) { .. }
```

In the above declaration number of rows need not be specified as we are not allocating the memory for the array hence can be ignored. Number of columns is required for the dimension of the array.

Comment: This is the most plausible answer because I have used this before

Comment: @IrrationalPerson This still allows you to pass a matrix of the wrong size. It is the same as `int determ(int (*a)[MAX]);`. The better solution it to pass the matrix by reference.

Comment: Alright, So what exactly is 'MAX'? Do I need to define it... is it part of a preprocessor?

Comment: @ATM Definitely not a preprocessor macro. You should be defining it.

Comment: @ATM It has to be a compile time constant.

Comment: Isn't better to define the function like `void determ(const int &a[][MAX], int n);`?

Comment: @juanchopanza: So how can I tell c++ that it (`MAX`) is a compile time constant, how must I define it?

Comment: @ATM For example `const size_t MAX = 42;`

Comment: @juanchopanza: using the **compile time constant** is working. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array by reference and have the function figure out the size of the matrix. To do this use a template as follows

```
template <int R>
int determ(int (&a)[R][R]) {
//now R is the number of rows
std::cout << R << std::endl;
// rest of code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways:

1) Declare your function as is:

```
int determ(int** a, int size, int n) {...} // 'size' aka 'MAX'
```

2) Use dynamic container such as std::vector:

```
int determ(const vector<vector<int>>& a, int n) {...}
```

Comment: Note that a vector of vectors is quite different to  2D array. It is more like an array of pointers to arrays.

Comment: @Alexey: I will try that, but if I may ask, what does int** a mean.

Comment: @ATM, it called "pointer to pointer" and essentially is a hint to compiler. The thing is, that with pointer 'int* a' you can write 'a[2] = 2' and similarly, with "int **a" - 'a[2][2] = 2'

Comment: What I did: `int determinant(int** oMat, int n)` But then I got an error at this line `det = det + oMat[0][p] * pow(-1,p) * determinant(sMat, n-1)`

Comment: @juanchopanza, yep, I was suggesting a better design solution, but you absolutely right: on the low-level they are quite different

Comment: @ATM, have a look here on your error: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584100/converting-multidimensional-arrays-to-pointers-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584100/converting-multidimensional-arrays-to-pointers-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

1. Use a compile time size like `MAX`, and declare your array parameter in terms of that:

   ```
   int determinant(int (*oMat)[MAX], int n) {
   ```

   With that you are passing a pointer to the first element (= row) of your 2D array. The same can be done with the `std::array<>` template:

   ```
   int determinant(array<array<int, MAX>, MAX> *oMat, int n) {
   ```

   However, in both cases `MAX` must be a compile time constant. You may pass `MAX` in as a template parameter, allowing different code to work on matrices of different size, but the problem remains that `MAX` needs to be a compile time constant.
2. If you want to work with a dynamic size in C++, you have two choices: First you can use a vector of vector

   ```
   int determinant(vector<vector<int> > *oMat, int n) {
   ```

   This allows maximum flexibility, however, it does not enforce that the lines have the same size. `oMat` could be a ragged 2D array. The other way is to use a 1D array and calculate the indexes yourself:

   ```
   int determinant(int size, int *oMat, int n) {
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
               //Access the individual elements with
               oMat[size*i + j];
   ```
3. The third approach is to drop back to C, because in contrast to C++, C allows for true dynamic 2D arrays:

   ```
   int determinant(int size, int (*oMat)[size], int n) {
       for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
           for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
               //Access the individual elements with
               oMat[i][j];
   ```

   You would create the array and call the function like this:

   ```
   int n = /*whatever*/;
   int (*matrix)[n] = malloc(n*sizeof(*matrix));
   fillMatrix(n, matrix);
   determinant(n, matrix, n);
   free(matrix);    //Don't forget the cleanup.
   ```

Comment: I would like to try option one, BUT what is a compile time size? How do use it... do I define `MAX`...?

Comment: Compile time constants mean that the value must be known by the compiler when it compiles the program, it cannot depend on anything that is only known when the program is run. Usually, these compile time constants are either `const` variables with global, namespace, or static class scope, plain literals like `7`, or passed to a template as a template argument. `array<7>` passes `7` as such a template argument to the `array<>` template. However, the value that's passed to a template argument must be a compile time constant itself, ie. `array<n>` won't do.